# Pattern comprehension with a single-node pattern in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Cypher, this works:

```
[ (n:some_label)-[]-() | n ]
```

But this does not:

```
[ (n:some_label) | n ]
```

Since `(n:some_label)` is a valid pattern that can be used in `MATCH`, it's not clear to me why this is. Is there a way to perform a pattern comprehension with a pattern matching just a single node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your current approach isn't possible (we do have an improvement request in the backlog) you can work around this by using a 0-length var-length pattern:

```
[ (n:some_label)-[*0]-() | n ]
```

That's effectively the same as a single node pattern. And no the number of actual relationships on the node itself doesn't change the behavior, the `*0` is basically an identity relationship...the node on the other side is the same `n` node.